# Add index to table if it does not exist

Tags: mysql, indexing, alter

I want to add an index to a table by using the `ALTER` syntax, but first check if it already exists on the table, and only add the index if it does not exist.

```
 ALTER TABLE tableName ADD INDEX IX_Table_XYZ (column1);
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try like this:

```
set @x := (select count(*) from information_schema.statistics where table_name = 'table' and index_name = 'IX_Table_XYZ' and table_schema = database());
set @sql := if( @x > 0, 'select ''Index exists.''', 'Alter Table TableName ADD Index IX_Table_XYZ (column1);');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Comment: This is the best answer!

Comment: @RahulTripathi Is it needed to DEALLOCATE the stmt? When does this apply?

Comment: @KayNelson:- DEALLOCATE is not needed. It is used basically if we are using things like cursor. You can refer this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html which says: *A prepared statement is specific to the session in which it was created. If you terminate a session without deallocating a previously prepared statement, the server deallocates it a*

Comment: @KayNelson:- Glad that I helped you as well!

Comment: This is equivalent to `IF NOT EXISTS` and it's a really bad idea. In the end you may end up with an old/obsolete definition of the index in production.

Answer (score 5):

You can check if the index (by name of the index) exists by using this syntax

```
SELECT 1        
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'yourschema' AND TABLE_NAME='yourtable' AND
INDEX_NAME='yourindex';
```

Then you could run it in a Stored Procedure like

```
IF (SELECT 1        
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'yourschema' AND TABLE_NAME='yourtable' AND
    INDEX_NAME='yourindex') != 1 THEN

Alter Table TableName ADD Index IX_Table_XYZ (column1);

END IF;
```

Comment: Thank you, but can this be done without store procedure.

Comment: Yes just execute it in `BEGIN ... END` statements. I always prefeer SP as then you can change logic on a production enviroment without shutting down the software.

Comment: @KayNelson How do i do this with a field?

Answer (score 4):

Based on @KayNelson's answer, for me in MySQL 5.7.16 the correct approach was to use `IS NULL` instead of `!=1` in the `IF` condition.

So a snippet to conditionally add `INDEX` to a table is:

```sql
IF (SELECT 1        
    FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`STATISTICS`
    WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'yourschema' 
    AND `TABLE_NAME` = 'yourtable'
    AND `INDEX_NAME` = 'yourindex') IS NULL THEN

    ALTER TABLE `yourtable` ADD INDEX `yourindex` (`column1` ASC);

END IF;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to check if `SHOW INDEX FROM yourTableName WHERE Key_name = 'yourTableIndexName'` returns any rows. If the result set isn't empty, the index exists already.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, and based on some answers above. Cleaned some code. Very easy approach.

Just change `@tablename` and `@columnname`:

```
SET @dbname = DATABASE();
SET @tablename = "tableName";
SET @columnname = "IX_Table_XYZ";
SET @preparedStatement = (SELECT IF(
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
    WHERE
      (table_name = @tablename)
      AND (table_schema = @dbname)
      AND (index_name = @columnname)
  ) > 0,
  "SELECT 1",
  CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ", @tablename, " ADD INDEX ", @columnname, " (", @columnname, ") USING BTREE;")
));
PREPARE alterIfNotExists FROM @preparedStatement;
EXECUTE alterIfNotExists;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE alterIfNotExists;
```